# Changing max number of blog posts per page doesn't work

Tags: options, blog

WP 3.2.1

Changing the max number of posts to show on each page via Settings->Reading isn't working.  Could [this reported bug](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/archives-not-showing-nextprev-windows-only-crazy?replies=5) be the culprit?

Comment: can you post your code?....

Comment: Can't, NDA.  That said, the blog loop is largely stock.

Comment: you probably use some custom theme with a function that override this . it can be nulled in many ways . to test if this is the case, switch to default theme and see if it works .

Comment: @krembo99 is probebly right... thats why without changing the theme code itself (we need to see it) it wont work.. the inTheme definition over-rules the wordpress backend

Comment: Unfortunately, the custom theme is the only theme installed.  I also came onto this project late, and don't have the authority to do what you suggest.  It's not my project, per se.  I'm just a subcontractor.

Comment: @kevinmajor1 - ask your supervisors for permission , otherwise, no one will be able to help. do you have ftp access? can you see the themes menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't work then there must be some problem or overwrite in your custom theme,

add this code in your index.php or where ever you want to show the custom number of posts,

```
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=1' );
```

change '1' to any number you want

Comment: this will work, but it is quite dangerous for someone who does not know his theme - it can change other queries that depends on that ...

Comment: this isn't dangerous :) go ahead and give a try :)

Comment: I agree with Krembo99 - although , like he pointed out - it WILL work - is some situations a global blanket change like this can also change other features - especially on more complicated themes.

Comment: for standard-loops in normal archive template files it's a great solution.